# Route error, deleting nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I created an applicacion where an user can save his max rep in weight lifted. Im getting an error when im creating the delete method.

My RM controller:

```
class RmsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @rm.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Repeticion maxima eliminada"
    redirect_to user_rms_path
  end
end
```

Index of rm (where im trying to delete)

```
<ul class="rms">

  <% @rms.each do |rm| %>
  <li>
    <%= p rm.content %>
    <%= p '-' %>
    <%= p rm.quantity  %>
    <% if !current_user?(@user) %>
      | <%= link_to "delete", @rm, method: :delete, 
                          data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
                          <% end %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
```

Im getting the next error:

> Routing Error No route matches [DELETE] "/users/1/rms"

This is my config routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',               to: 'users#new'
  get    '/contact',              to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/about',                to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/login',                to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',                to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',               to: 'sessions#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :users do
    resources :rms 
  end
  resources :trainings do
    resources :bookings
  end
end
```

rake routes command:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                         Controller#Action
                   root GET    /                                                   static_pages#home
                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                                   users#new
                contact GET    /contact(.:format)                                  static_pages#contact
                  about GET    /about(.:format)                                    static_pages#about
                  login GET    /login(.:format)                                    sessions#new
                        POST   /login(.:format)                                    sessions#create
                 logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                                   sessions#destroy
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format)             account_activations#edit
        password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)                          password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)                      password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)                 password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)                      password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)                      password_resets#update
               user_rms GET    /users/:user_id/rms(.:format)                       rms#index
                        POST   /users/:user_id/rms(.:format)                       rms#create
            new_user_rm GET    /users/:user_id/rms/new(.:format)                   rms#new
           edit_user_rm GET    /users/:user_id/rms/:id/edit(.:format)              rms#edit
                user_rm GET    /users/:user_id/rms/:id(.:format)                   rms#show
                        PATCH  /users/:user_id/rms/:id(.:format)                   rms#update
                        PUT    /users/:user_id/rms/:id(.:format)                   rms#update
                        DELETE /users/:user_id/rms/:id(.:format)                   rms#destroy
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                                    users#index
                        POST   /users(.:format)                                    users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                           users#edit
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                users#show
                        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                users#update
                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                users#update
                        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                users#destroy
      training_bookings GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#index
                        POST   /trainings/:training_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#create
   new_training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/new(.:format)      bookings#new
  edit_training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id/edit(.:format) bookings#edit
       training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#show
                        PATCH  /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#update
                        PUT    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#update
                        DELETE /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#destroy
              trainings GET    /trainings(.:format)                                trainings#index
                        POST   /trainings(.:format)                                trainings#create
           new_training GET    /trainings/new(.:format)                            trainings#new
          edit_training GET    /trainings/:id/edit(.:format)                       trainings#edit
               training GET    /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#show
                        PATCH  /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#update
                        PUT    /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#update
                        DELETE /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#destroy
```

I would like to know why i am getting this error and how i can fix it, so the Max rep can be deleted whenever an user wants.

Comment: `<%= link_to "delete", [@user, rm], method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>`, show `Rm` and `User` Model with `index` action code  rms_controller, also you should use `Rm.find` instead of `@rm.find` in `destroy` action

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass proper route in  link_to tag. Run rake routes for RmsController and find out destroy path(ex: user_rms_path).

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
      | <%= link_to "delete", [@user, @rm], method: :delete, 
                          data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
                          <% end %>
```

Try this out it will work.

Comment: what's the path for destroy in rake routes,  you also need to pass id

Comment: try to find user in RmsController destroy action and in view do this link_to "delete", [@user, @rm]

Comment: Now its showing the following error: **Nil location provided. Can't build URI.**

Comment: Do you have @user in you RmsController? try to find user in RmsController destroy action.

Comment: In you routes for you don't have DELETE /users/:user_id/rms/:id(.:format).

Comment: yes i do, sorry that was whe i was trying something.. updated with actual rake routes